# android service to detect launching of an applcation

Tags: android, service

I am starting a service which detects whenever an application is launched by the user and shows a toast with the name of the application.

```
package com.xylon.serviceexample;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service{

    private static final String TAG = "MyService";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Congrats! MyService Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcessInfo = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for (int i = 0; i < runningAppProcessInfo.size(); i++) {

            Log.v("Proc: ", runningAppProcessInfo.get(i).processName);
            Toast.makeText(this, runningAppProcessInfo.get(i).processName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }




        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");  
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyService Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    }
}
```

Have I placed the ActivityManager code at correct place? It shows me the applications which are already running on the device when the service is started.

Comment: So what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using READ LOGS and then trace that from logcat..

add this in manifest file:

```
android.permission.READ_LOGS
```

Code:

```
try
    {
        Process mLogcatProc = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        mLogcatProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"logcat", "-d"});

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mLogcatProc.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        final StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
        String separator = System.getProperty("line.separator"); 

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            log.append(line);
            log.append(separator);
        }
        String w = log.toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),w, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

but from API 16, google is restrict this thing so now we cant trace this thing.